# Drawing Shapes within a QGraphicsItem (parent) with positions relative to the parent

Tags: qt, paint, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

I have my own object implementing a `QGraphicsItem` - it is essentially just a square with a border. I am attempting to draw shapes within that item, using it as the parent. The issue is that the coordinates I am using for the shapes within the parent are not relative to the parent's coordinates, but rather the scene.

Example: I want to draw a `QGraphicsLineItem` within my `QGraphicsItem` (the parent). The parent is at 50,50, with dimensions 20x20. If I draw a line with the parent specified, using coordinates 0,0,20,20, it draws at 0,0,20,20 relative to the scene, not the parent.

Is there a way to make the line (or any other shape) use positions relative the parent, not the scene? Or would I need to manually determine the coordinates by checking the parent's X and Y?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about you make each of your `QGraphicsItem`s also inherit from `QObject`, and pass a parent to each?.
Then, determine the position in the scene based on the parent coords (recursive):

```
class Scene(QGraphicsScene):

    def __init__(self):
        QGraphicsScene.__init__(self)

    def xpos(self):
        return 0

    def ypos(self):
        return 0


class RelativeItem(QGraphicsRectItem, QObject):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        QGraphicsRectItem.__init__(self)
        QObject.__init__(self, parent)

    def xpos(self):
        return self.scenePos().x() - self.parent().xpos()

    def ypos(self):
        return self.scenePos().y() - self.parent().ypos()

scene = QGraphicsScene()
obj1 = RelativeItem(scene)  # Relative to scene
obj2 = RelativeItem(obj1)  # Relative to obj1
```

`xpos()` and `ypos()` recursively calls the parent's `xpos()` and `ypos()` (the scene is hard-coded at `(0, 0)`), and subtracts it from the object's position in the scene. This means that the two functions return the x and y positions of the object relative to the parent.

Comment: Thanks - this is essentially what I am planning to do.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that comes to my mind is to use `QGraphicsItem::mapToScene` on the parent item before setting childs drawing coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `QGraphicsItem::setParentItem` and referring to the `QGraphicsItem::parentItem` when setting your `QGraphicsLineItem`'s position?